# creating an histogram through time

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, histogram, visualization

I have a dictionary ordered according to time (value 1 is the first timestamp and 2 is the second), in each of them theres another dictionary with values(keys don't matter), I want to create a histogram for few types of values and go through time, so it will be <0.01, <0.1, <0, <1, <10, <100.
and do this for every timestep so it will look something like that:
[image]

so as you see each histogram is in another step, and we see how much cells had a value correspoding to the values in Y axis.

Comment: Please add the entire dictionary to your question.